# Problems adding Devise model to a RefineryCMS app

Tags: devise, refinerycms

I'd like to add a Devise model to a RefineryCMS app to allow a customer to log in and manage their profile. It seems reasonable to do this since a customer has nothing to do with the CMS.  Since RefineryCMS uses Devise, I thought this would be a simple thing to do.  I'm starting from a blank slate, not integrating with an existing app.

Steps to reproduce the issue I'm having:

```
$ refinerycms my_fun_app
$ cd my_fun_app
$ rails generate devise customer
$ rake db:migrate
```

After doing the steps above I fire up the app (using `rails server`) and go to `http://localhost:3000` I get prompted to create a Refinery user.  All is well.

The problem is when I go to `http://localhost:3000/customers/sign_up` I get a `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `customer_registration_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00000003cc9810>
```

The error is raise from this line in /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-2.0.5/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with RefineryCMS as it is based on Devise and setups Devise as its own way:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # Please do not change the router_name away from :refinery
  # otherwise Refinery may not function properly. Thanks!
  config.router_name = :refinery
end
```

So inside Devise, the URL helpers couldn't find the one defined in your app.

There seems no official solution for this problem and RefineryCMS guys are working on this so it may be fixed in the future releases. However, there is one good article regarding how to integrate Refinery and Devise into your existing Rails 3.2 App, which may give you some thoughts: http://sdownie.com/blogs/integrating-refinery-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-rails-app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line of code:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => customer_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing the url to the hardcoded path.  For example, if you run rake routes and get:

```
$ bundle exec rake routes | grep devise
cancel_customer_registration GET    /customers/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       customer_registration POST   /customers(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_customer_registration GET    /customers/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_customer_registration GET    /customers/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                             PUT    /customers(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /customers(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

then you would change this line of code:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => "/customers") do |f| %>
```